# Simulated Maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, simulation

How to estimate the parameters of the variable from which we make draws in MSLE. 
For example, 
Consider (example from Cameron and Trivedi-12.4.5 Unobserved heterogeneity)
$$ y_i=\theta +u_i+\epsilon$$

I am interested in getting value of theta to get that I use MSLE. For using MSLE we make draws from u but how do I approach the problem if I don't know the parameters of u.

Meaning if I know the distribution of u but it has unknown parameter how do I get theta and parameters of u?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you think $u_i$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and an unknown standard deviation $\sigma$. Now you have two parameters in your likelihood function and you maximize both. You start with starting values. Now you draw your sample of $u_i$ given that starting value. The next iteration you will get improved guesses of these parameters, and use those for drawing your $u_i$. You continue iterating till convergence.

Comment: Just to be clear: I draw values of u now I just don't know theta. Now I enter the log likelihood loop to get best theta for that particular draw of u. I take an average for all the draws. I get the best possible theta. But the problem is : I assume some sigma for my draws, how do I get to real sigma. Can you be more descriptive in your explanation?

Comment: Sigma isn't fixed in this algorithm, it to is updated each iteration.

Comment: @MaartenBuis, (+1) but how do you establish convergence if there are other unknown parameters in the model, apart from those simulatied via sampling?

Comment: you continue till the maximum change from one iteration to the next is below your chosen cut-off